# React-Query: useMutation's onSuccess to update chache but the cache seemed still

Tags: react-hooks, react-query, react-typescript

I wrote two React typescript projects with basically similar structures. They both used react-query to fetch data. The first code snippet is as below, and it worked as expected:

```
export function PostsPage() {
  const { isLoading, data: posts } = useQuery(['postsData'], getPosts);
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const { mutate } = useMutation(savePost, {
    onSuccess: (savedPost) => {
      queryClient.setQueryData<PostData[]>({
        queryKey: ['postsData'],
    queryFn: (oldPosts) => {
          if (oldPosts === undefined) return [savedPost];
          else return [savedPost, ...oldPosts];
        });
    },
  });
  if (isLoading || posts === undefined) 
    return <div className="w-96 mx-auto mt-6">Loading ...</div>;
  return (
    <div className="w-96 mx-auto mt-6">
      <h2 className="text-xl text-slate-900 font-bold">Posts</h2>
      <NewPostForm onSave={mutate} />
      <PostsList posts={posts} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The `posts` variable's cache would be updated once I clicked the button related to `onSave` and the `PostsList` would immediately update, adding a new post item according to the cache.
However for the second code:

```
export function RepoPage() {
  const [searchCriteria, setSearchCriteria] = useState<SearchCriteria | undefined>();
  const { data } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['repo', searchCriteria],
    queryFn: () => getRepo(searchCriteria as SearchCriteria),
    enabled: searchCriteria !== undefined,
  });

  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const { mutate } = useMutation({
    mutationFn: starRepo,
    onSuccess: () => {
      queryClient.setQueryData<RepoData>(['repo', searchCriteria], (repo) => {
        if (repo === undefined) return undefined;
        return {
          ...repo,
          totalCount: repo.repository.stargazers.totalCount + 1,
          viewerHasStarred: true,
        };
      });
    },
  });

  function handleSearch(search: SearchCriteria) {
    setSearchCriteria(search);
  }
  function handleStarClick() {
    if (data) mutate(data.repository.id);
  }

  return (
    <main className="max-w-xs ml-auto mr-auto">
      <SearchRepoForm onSearch={handleSearch} />
      {data && (
        <>
          <FoundRepo
            name={data.repository.name}
            description={data.repository.description}
            stars={data.repository.stargazers.totalCount}
          />
          {!data.repository.viewerHasStarred && <StarRepoButton onClick={handleStarClick} />}
        </>
      )}
    </main>
  );
}
```

When I clicked `StarRepoButton` and `useMutation` was successfully invoked, the returned new values of `totalCount` and `viewerHasStarred` fields in the cache didn't render and `StarRepoButton` still showed itself and didn't disappear. Only when the browser lost regained focus again did the data refetch and render a new one, but not from cache as expected. But I expected this to behave the same as the first one and could use only cache to immediately render the returned value in `onSuccess` and make the `StarRepoButton` disappear according to the boolean value. What's the problem or what may be the difference between the two codes?

I tried to change the `queryKey` to only one string, i.e. `queryKey: ['repo']` but it didn't work. I don't want to reroute to this page in `onSuccess` to immediately rerender because I'm a learner and want to figure out why the two snippets worked differently.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have information about the `data` type returned from `useQuery`. However, I have an assumtion that it is something like :

```js
type GetRepoQueryData = {
  repository: {
    viewerHasStarred: boolean;
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

Let's call it `GetRepoQueryData`

Inside the `onSuccess` function you call `setQueryData`. It should return `GetRepoQueryData` as well

You modify `data.viewerHasStarred`, but the original `data.repository.viewerHasStarred` remains unmodified. That's why your button is still visible.

So, you should set the data like this:

```js
queryClient.setQueryData<GetRepoQueryData>(['repo', searchCriteria], (oldData) => {
        if (oldData === undefined) return undefined;
        return {
          repository: {
            viewerHasStarred: true,
            ...oldData.repository
          }
          ...oldData
        };
      });
```

[Documentation reference](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/reference/QueryClient#queryclientsetquerydata)